# Consuming a REST API in Java

Tags: java, rest

I need to consume REST API. There are many REST clients for Java. Are there any areas of concerns before proceeding this?

Comment: Your client being code that is run behind SOAP is of no relevance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) for that. However, if you are working on a spring enabled project, I would recommend using [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

Rest template provides an abstraction over HTTP client as a result of which you will not have to deal with serialization/deserialition, error handling, SSL configuration in every part of code where you make a REST call. You will just need to configure those with REST template configuration once and not worry about it. This makes your code clean and easily maintainable in case you wish to change the way your application talks to the back-end restful application in future.